# SQL select from Table1 that has no value in Table2

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the following data:

Table 1:

```
NUMBER1 | NUMBER2 | TYPE
101       201       A
101       202       A
101       203       A
101       204       A
102       211       A
102       212       A
102       213       A
```

Table 2:

```
NUMBER1 | NUMBER2 | TYPE
101       201       B
101       202       B
101       203       B
102       211       B
102       212       B
```

Then I used a join for this Table 3:

```
NUMBER1 | NUMBER2 | TYPE
101       201       A
101       201       B
101       202       A
101       202       B
101       203       A
101       203       B
101       204       A
102       211       A
102       211       B
102       212       A
102       212       B
102       213       A
```

I need to get the row with **101 - 204 - A** and **102 - 213 - A**.

Data is available in Table 1 but has no data aligned in Table 2.

Is there a way to get this?

PS: This is dummy data.

Comment: *Then I used join for this `table3`*: please show us your existing query.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> SQLite: I removed these conflicting tags,please tag only the one database product that you are using.

Comment: You don't need to SHOUT, your inside voice is fine, we can read you quite clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join and select only the records having null in the right table in some column which shouldn't be null if there was a corresponding record.

```
SELECT a.NUMBER1, a.NUMBER2, a.TYPE
FROM
    Table_1 a
    LEFT JOIN Table_2 b
        ON a.NUMBER1 = b.NUMBER1 AND
           a.NUMBER2 = b.NUMBER2
WHERE
    b.NUMBER1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows in `A` that are not in `B`, then you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.number1 = a.number1 and b.number2 = a.number2
                 );
```